# centos8 install appium failed:errno ENOENT appium-windows-driver@1.18.1 install: `node install-npm.js`

Tags: appium-android, centos8

install nodejs:

```
yum install gcc-c++ openssl-devel
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.0/node-v14.17.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
tar -xvf node-v14.17.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
vi /etc/profile
# nodejs PATH
export NODE_HOME=/home/selenium/node-v14.17.0-linux-x64
export PATH=$NODE_HOME/bin:$PATH
source /etc/profile
```

when I run

```
npm install -g appium
```

> sh: node: command not found 
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! syscall spawn
> npm ERR! file sh
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> npm ERR! appium-windows-driver@1.18.1 install: `node install-npm.js`
> npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the appium-windows-driver@1.18.1 install script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-05-14T05_06_33_166Z-debug.log

when I run

```
node --version
```

it can print curreent node version:v14.17.0
anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

```
nvm install node
```

use this command to install node,then I can successfully install appium.